# Agent Orion JSON MQTT

Tags: fiware

I have been able to send JSON format measures via MQTT publisher to the mosquitto docker container ( that is a broker ), also i have been able to pass that data to the IOT-Agent, these are curl commands that i used to create a service-path and to register a device on the IOT-Agent:

```
curl -iX POST 'http://localhost:4041/iot/services' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Fiware-Service: myClassRoom' -H 'Fiware-ServicePath: /' -d '{ "services": [ { "apikey": "12345", "cbroker": "http://localhost:1026", "entity_type": "Device", "resource": /iot/d" } ] }
```

This is how i registered the device in the IOT-Agent:

```
curl -iX POST 'http://localhost:4041/iot/devices' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Fiware-Service: myClassRoom' -H 'Fiware-ServicePath: /' -d '{ "devices": [ { "device_id": "SensTemp", "entity_name": "urn:ngsi-ld:temperature-sensor:001", "entity_type": "Device", "protocol": "PDI-IoTA-UltraLight", "transport": "MQTT", "timezone": "Europe/Madrid", "attributes":[ { "object_id": "temperature", "name": "temperature", "type": "Integer"} ] } ] }'
```

And this is the error that is giving me in the Agent, can someone help me to solve this issue?

```
fiware-agent    | time=2022-07-25T08:19:11.562Z | lvl=FATAL | corr=n/a | trans=n/a | op=IoTAgentNGSI.Global | from=n/a | srv=n/a | subsrv=n/a | msg=An unexpected exception has been raised. Ignoring: TypeError: parsedMessage.reduce is not a function
```

And here is the evidence of connecting, Service Path, information about the device etc...

```
fiware-agent    | time=2022-07-25T08:20:11.931Z | lvl=DEBUG | corr=785bb065-6c0a-41ba-96d2-182f0040ea93 | trans=785bb065-6c0a-41ba-96d2-182f0040ea93 | op=IOTAUL.IoTUtils | from=n/a | srv=n/a | subsrv=n/a | msg=deviceData after merge with conf: {"_id":"62d931f861815b54e26fa2b2","active":[{"object_id":"temperature","name":"temperature","type":"Integer"}],"commands":[],"staticAttributes":[],"subscriptions":[],"creationDate":"2022-07-21T11:01:12.968Z","id":"SensTemp","type":"Device","name":"urn:ngsi-ld:temperature-sensor:001","service":"myclassroom","subservice":"/","internalId":null,"protocol":"PDI-IoTA-UltraLight","transport":"MQTT","explicitAttrs":false,"lazy":null,"internalAttributes":null} | comp=IoTAgent
```

And here is what i dont understand, why is giving me that error, parsed message error?

```
fiware-agent    | time=2022-07-25T08:20:11.932Z | lvl=DEBUG | corr=785bb065-6c0a-41ba-96d2-182f0040ea93 | trans=785bb065-6c0a-41ba-96d2-182f0040ea93 | op=IOTAUL.Common.Binding | from=n/a | srv=n/a | subsrv=n/a | msg=Processing multiple measures for device [SensTemp] with apiKey [12345] | comp=IoTAgent
fiware-agent    | time=2022-07-25T08:20:11.932Z | lvl=DEBUG | corr=785bb065-6c0a-41ba-96d2-182f0040ea93 | trans=785bb065-6c0a-41ba-96d2-182f0040ea93 | op=IOTAUL.Common.Binding | from=n/a | srv=n/a | subsrv=n/a | msg=Parse error parsing incoming message [%]. Forcing to hex string | comp=IoTAgent {"temperature": 47}

fiware-agent    | time=2022-07-25T08:20:11.932Z | lvl=DEBUG | corr=785bb065-6c0a-41ba-96d2-182f0040ea93 | trans=785bb065-6c0a-41ba-96d2-182f0040ea93 | op=IOTAUL.Common.Binding | from=n/a | srv=n/a | subsrv=n/a | msg=stringMessage: [7b2274656d7065726174757265223a2034377d] parsedMessage: [7b2274656d7065726174757265223a2034377d] | comp=IoTAgent
```

And Why cant i see the Temperature change in the MongoDB depository?
Thank you !!!

Comment: Please post the text, not an image, It's totally unreadable.

Comment: "Parse error, parsed incoming message", what can that mean? My message is sent from raspberry as a mqtt publisher, here are some details about that: THE_TOPIC= "/ul/12345/SensTemp/attrs", and the message details are: s = {} , s['temperature'] = random.randint(0,100), j = json.dumps(s), msg_to_be_sent = j, print(j) client.publish(THE_TOPIC, payload=msg_to_be_sent, qos=1, retain=False) ... Maybe the error is in message that is published?

Comment: Topic `/ul/12345/SensTemp/attrs` would seem to indicate you are using Ultralight not JSON.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, yes, the problem was in the agent! Yes i have made an error when designing an agent, the agent should be designed as an JSON agent!

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved! The error was in the Agent, I was using Ultralight IOT Agent. The solution is simple, when i used IOT JSON agent the problem was solved!
Now the Agent tells me that the measures are updated successfully!